# Can you suggest similr event for TextChange event of a TextBox in .Net WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

I have to do complex calculations on every textchange event of a WPF textbox , Is there any similar event ?

Comment: if it's complex and takes a lot, don't do it at every single text change :)

Comment: so Davide How to identify that change is minor or major

Comment: you can employ a timed approach, where you can start a stopwatch when a change is made, and for all changes that are made within a delta period, you perform a single computation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make use of Binding for that and make sure sure any change to the bound item gets triggered:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=X, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

and then in your viewModel you can do calculations based on that change (your ViewModel should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public int MyProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return myVar ;
            }
            set
            {
                myVar = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty") ;

                //Fire off calculation in another thread in here

            }
        }
```